# A need to create a complex sql statement

Tags: sql, sqlite

I have two tables.

```
table A
id
isReachEnd
```

---

```
table B
id
isFree
```

I need to fetch all id's which satisfy  next criterion:

```
((A.id = B.id) AND (A.isReachEnd = 1) AND (B.isFree = 1))
```

How can I do?

Comment: You're not showing any research effort. This is basic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT *
FROM A, B
WHERE A.id = B.id AND A.isReachEnd = 1 AND B.isFree = 1
```

Answer (score 2):

This is not complex at all -- it's very simple, in fact. The query would be just be

```
SELECT * FROM a, b WHERE a.id = b.id AND a.isReachEnd = 1 AND b.isFree = 1
```